# make check produces ERROR (GLib-ERROR **: 17:50:29.132) when installing QEMU Emulator on OSX

Tags: c, glib

Got below ERROR when installing QEMU Emulator on OSX (following the steps in the bottom lines of https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2018/tools.html):

```
ERROR: (tests/test-string-output-visitor:4303): GLib-ERROR **: 17:50:29.132: duplicate test case path: /string-visitor/output/int
make: *** [check-tests/test-string-output-visitor] Error 1
```

What does this ERROR mean? How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an error with (older) QEMU in combination with a newer GLib. See https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/526287/.

The [patch suggested in the link above](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/526287/raw/):

```
diff --git a/tests/test-string-output-visitor.c b/tests/test-string-output-visitor.c
index 101fb27..fd5e67b 100644
--- a/tests/test-string-output-visitor.c
+++ b/tests/test-string-output-visitor.c
@@ -248,39 +248,39 @@ int main(int argc, char **argv)

     output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/int",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_int, false);
-    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/int",
+    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/int-human",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_int, true);
     output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/bool",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_bool, false);
-    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/bool",
+    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/bool-human",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_bool, true);
     output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/number",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_number, false);
-    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/number",
+    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/number-human",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_number, true);
     output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/string",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_string, false);
-    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/string",
+    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/string-human",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_string, true);
     output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/no-string",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_no_string,
                             false);
-    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/no-string",
+    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/no-string-human",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_no_string,
                             true);
     output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/enum",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_enum, false);
-    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/enum",
+    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/enum-human",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_enum, true);
     output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/enum-errors",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_enum_errors,
                             false);
-    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/enum-errors",
+    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/enum-errors-human",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_enum_errors,
                             true);
     output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/intList",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_intList, false);
-    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/intList",
+    output_visitor_test_add("/string-visitor/output/intList-human",
                             &out_visitor_data, test_visitor_out_intList, true);

     g_test_run();
```

Comment: Solved, following this answer. Thanks.